# alfresco, tomcat crashes on startup, no clues in the logs

Tags: windows, tomcat, troubleshooting, startup, alfresco

I have installed an alfresco community edition 4.0 on a Win 2003 R2 with 3GB of RAM. 
I've used alfresco for some hours, i've created a user, uploaded some documents. But now, restarting it, tomcat crashes during startup.

The logs are VERY poor: these are the last lines of `conf/jakarta_service_20120420.log`

```
[2012-04-20 15:45:07] [info] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.2.0) started
[2012-04-20 15:45:07] [info] Running Service...
[2012-04-20 15:45:07] [info] Starting service...
[2012-04-20 15:45:08] [info] Service started in 1296 ms.
```

The last lines of `conf/stderr_20120420.log`

```
20-apr-2012 15.45.09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
20-apr-2012 15.45.09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
20-apr-2012 15.45.09 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor alfresco.xml
20-apr-2012 15.45.10 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
20-apr-2012 15.45.12 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

The `conf/stdout_20120420`.log is empty.

I need to improve the troubleshooting process so:
**1) how to increase the log level?**

I replaced "FINE" the with "ALL" in conf/logging.properties, but nothing changed.

**2) any other suggestion on troubleshooting startup is appreciated :-)**

Comment: 1296ms looks much much too quick for a real Alfresco repo to start up, I wonder if just Tomcat is starting without Alfresco. Did you try checking your alfresco.log to see if that tells you what has gone wrong?

Comment: Well, it seems something is going wrong in launch script because I find an EMPTY aflresco.log in c:\WINDOWS\system32 ... is it supposed to be there? i launch alfresco from command line, like this: C:\Alfresco>servicerun START

Comment: I think your windows service definition might be stuffed, as that doesn't sound quite right, but I can't be sure as I always use Alfresco on Linux....

Comment: Have you tried starting up Tomcat, then looking at the Tomcat status page to see if it's even seeing the Alfresco webapp?

Answer (score 1):

For loglevel look in `..\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties`

I'm usually using :

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=debug
```